# MP3 file's duration infinity in desktop / iOS SAFARI

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, html5-video, html5-audio

I am trying to play this audio file in a native html5 audio tag. IN **DESKTOP SAFARI** / **iOS SAFARI**

here is the link to the file: `https://primetime.a.bluejeans.com/a2m/static/6a1ea7f4ef34458f0b9b/static/a2m_player/intro_bgm.mp3`

Now, it has a couple of issues:

1. The duration is **INFINITY** ( checked after `loadedmetadata` event, and also after every `timeupdate`.
2. The audio doesn't play fully, it **stops abruptly with NO errors** at random times, ex at 50th second / 72nd second. the last event in this case is `timeupdate` only.
3. Html5 media tag's controls show "**Live Broadcast**". ( in the UI I mean )

below are the request and responses recorded from Charles (2 requests/responses):

REQUEST 1:

```
GET /a2m/static/6a1ea7f4ef34458f0b9b/static/a2m_player/intro_bgm.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: primetime.a.bluejeans.com
Accept-Language: en-us
X-Playback-Session-Id: 174A3981-F3E3-4F49-A17B-BEBE88764552
Icy-Metadata: 1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Safari/605.1.15
Referer: https://fiddle.jshell.net/
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

RESPONSE 1 (showing only header):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: l4souPN96kHUVyThsqJZHllkVN873tbsPwk80hq94cixXcRKl3CTdO6HS32AbutMLInBSOXAZe8=
x-amz-request-id: 4122A053E2768F35
x-amz-replication-status: COMPLETED
x-amz-version-id: jAKAQ6MTbVed.NthIiH9ZOoLEWHRC95Z
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2020 16:43:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400 ; includeSubDomains ; preload
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

REQUEST 2:

```
GET /a2m/static/6a1ea7f4ef34458f0b9b/static/a2m_player/intro_bgm.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: primetime.a.bluejeans.com
Accept-Language: en-us
X-Playback-Session-Id: 174A3981-F3E3-4F49-A17B-BEBE88764552
Icy-Metadata: 1
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Safari/605.1.15
Referer: https://fiddle.jshell.net/
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

RESPONSE 2:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
x-amz-id-2: l4souPN96kHUVyThsqJZHllkVN873tbsPwk80hq94cixXcRKl3CTdO6HS32AbutMLInBSOXAZe8=
x-amz-request-id: 4122A053E2768F35
x-amz-replication-status: COMPLETED
x-amz-version-id: jAKAQ6MTbVed.NthIiH9ZOoLEWHRC95Z
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Server: AmazonS3
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Wed, 25 Nov 2020 16:43:00 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: false
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=86400 ; includeSubDomains ; preload
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

*CHECK OUT THE ISSUE LIVE: https://jsfiddle.net/y7whr25a/2/*

**Also please note that I have tried many answers from the web such as checking if server supports Range Requests (yes it does) and adding Range / Content Length /  Accepted Ranges / 206 http response code By rewriting request/response in Charles but nothing worked, I'm about to lose all hope.**

**here is the same file but hosted on google drive, THIS WORKS IDK HOW:** https://drive.google.com/u/1/uc?id=1b6UcqEb5_opUIR2eLzMghtAIQGYV2q8f&export=download

Answer (score 5):

Your file is not properly built and misses metadata information telling the duration.
You should reencode it properly if you want it to work everywhere.

Chrome and Firefox *(actually ffmpeg)* are able to *estimate* this duration from the bitrate, but even then, it may be inacccurate.

But the problem with Safari is that your server doesn't accept Range requests. Somehow, Safari switches to stream player in this case.

One way to make this browser be able to read this file entirely without changing the server config is to first fetch it **entirely** as a Blob, and to generate a `blob://` URI from there:

```js
(async () => {
  const src = "https://primetime.a.bluejeans.com/a2m/static/6a1ea7f4ef34458f0b9b/static/a2m_player/intro_bgm.mp3";
  const blob = await fetch( src )
    .then( (resp) => resp.blob() );
  const audio = new Audio( URL.createObjectURL( blob ) );
  audio.controls = true;
  document.body.append( audio );
  audio.addEventListener( "loadedmetadata", (evt) =>
    console.log( audio.duration )
  );
})();
```

Comment: Yes sir @Kaiido this seems to work Thankyou very much, but I am ready to re encode it, problem is I don't know much about the metadata and what actually needs to be fixed, could you please guide me so I can fix the audio itself, I cannot download the entire file before playing due to bandwidth reasons...

Comment: also if I download this file and upload to drive, create a google drive url and use it, everything works fine..

Comment: To reencode it you can use any web service that proposes reencoding audio formats (there are a lot). If you want to do it yourself you can install ffmpeg on your machine, then  `ffmpeg -i intro_bgm.mp3 fixed.mp3`. And I don't know why it works from GDrive, maybe their response header has something that Safari likes more... maybe they reencoded it...

Comment: So what I did was, I uploaded the mp3 to drive and downloaded it from there, and uploaded it back to my servers and still it shows "Live Broadcast" , which should mean the issue must be from server side only right? the headers and the way it's served? google drive is doing it perfectly

Comment: Serving it from my localhost I had the same issue, so GDrive is doing something. Maybe not perfect though, can you check it's actually able to perform a Range Request when served from there?

Comment: Yes, from drive it does so perfectly, first request 0 to 1/n and next 0 to n-1/n whre n is total no of bytes, here is the drive link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b6UcqEb5_opUIR2eLzMghtAIQGYV2q8f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: should I add drive request/response headers in this question details?

Comment: I don't get it, this link doesn't serves the file, do you mean from their own player it works well, or do you mean you have an other url where you can point your element to?

Comment: you can click download to get the link, here: https://drive.google.com/u/1/uc?id=1b6UcqEb5_opUIR2eLzMghtAIQGYV2q8f, this is playable, sorry I wasn't clearer

Comment: Oh actually `primetime.a.bluejeans.com` server doesn't accept Range requests. I'll have to check why it didn't work from my localhost then <edit>now it works...</edit>, but still your file need to be reencoded anyway.

Comment: OH, I just curled 0-100 bytes and it downloaded entire thing. I am looking into it.. Thanks

Comment: Yes same here ;-) Edited the answer, thnks for the follow up

Comment: I'll get back to you after the ops team enables support for range requests..