# Web Audio API analyzer output is dependent upon how HTML audio element source is defined

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari, web-audio-api

## Background

I have this code to visualize audio with HTML canvas. It works fine on Safari:

```js
window.MyNamespace = {} // Easy access to some vars by namespace.

// Some browsers require a user gesture before creating Web Audio API context.
MyNamespace.firstUserGesture = true

MyNamespace.audio = {}

MyNamespace.audio.el = document.getElementById("aud")

MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl = document.getElementById("canvasEl")

function setupCanvas() {
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.style.width = "88%"
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.style.height = "100px"

  // High dpi stuff.
  // Controls the chart line stroke thickness.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.width = 500 * 2
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.height = 100 * 2

  // Get canvas context.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx = MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.getContext("2d")

  // Set stroke color.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "#4285F4"

  // Draw twice as thick lines due to high dpi scaling.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2

  // Animation reference.
  MyNamespace.audio.canvasAnimation = {}

  MyNamespace.audio.el.addEventListener('play', () => drawWave())
  MyNamespace.audio.el.addEventListener('pause', () => cancelAnimationFrame(MyNamespace.audio.canvasAnimation))
  MyNamespace.audio.el.addEventListener('ended', () => cancelAnimationFrame(MyNamespace.audio.canvasAnimation))

  let N = 0 // Data count to show.
  N = MyNamespace.audio.analyzer.fftSize
  MyNamespace.audio.data = new Uint8Array(N)

  // Our drawing method
  function drawWave() {
    MyNamespace.audio.analyzer.getByteTimeDomainData(MyNamespace.audio.data)

    const WIDTH = MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.width
    const HEIGHT = MyNamespace.audio.canvasEl.height
    const bufferLength = MyNamespace.audio.data.length
    const dataArray = MyNamespace.audio.data

    // https://github.com/mdn/voice-change-o-matic-float-data/blob/c745ba8b48d7a9b93661ac43da2886633c06f2a7/scripts/app.js#L190
    MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
    MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    var barWidth = (WIDTH / bufferLength) * 2.5
    var barHeight
    var x = 0

    for (var j = 0; j < bufferLength; j++) {
      // 128 means no sound? 128 corresponds to 0? Log indicates so!
      // Multiply by 2 to make it more noticable.
      barHeight = Math.abs(dataArray[j] - 128) * 2
      //console.log('bar height', barHeight)

      MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(' + Math.floor(barHeight + 66) + ',133,244)'
      MyNamespace.audio.canvasCtx.fillRect(x, Math.abs(HEIGHT - barHeight) / 2, barWidth, barHeight)

      x += barWidth + 1
    }

    // Animate
    MyNamespace.audio.canvasAnimation = requestAnimationFrame(drawWave)
  }
}

function createAudio() {
  if (MyNamespace.firstUserGesture) {
    // Note: As a consequence of calling createMediaElementSource(),
    // audio playback from the HTMLMediaElement will be re-routed into the processing graph of the AudioContext.
    // So playing/pausing the media can still be done through the media element API and the player controls.
    if ('webkitAudioContext' in window) {
      MyNamespace.ctx = new webkitAudioContext()
      console.log('webkitAudioContext() is available.')
    } else if ('AudioContext' in window) {
      MyNamespace.ctx = new AudioContext()
      console.log('AudioContext() is available.')
    } else {
      console.log('Web Audio API is not available.')
    }

    MyNamespace.audio.source = MyNamespace.ctx.createMediaElementSource(MyNamespace.audio.el)
    MyNamespace.audio.analyzer = MyNamespace.ctx.createAnalyser()
    MyNamespace.audio.source.connect(MyNamespace.audio.analyzer)
    MyNamespace.audio.source.connect(MyNamespace.ctx.destination)
    console.log('Web Audio API is all set')
    // We are sure Web Audio API context is ready.
    setupCanvas()
  }
  MyNamespace.firstUserGesture = false
}

function handleClick() {
  // The AudioContext is not allowed to start before user gesture.
  // It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page.
  createAudio()

  // Play/pause the media
  if (MyNamespace.audio.el.paused) {
    MyNamespace.audio.el.play()
  } else {
    MyNamespace.audio.el.pause()
  }
}

MyNamespace.audio.btnEl = document.getElementById("btn")
MyNamespace.audio.btnEl.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>Micrufun</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="logo.ico" />
</head>

<body>
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <button id="btn">Play/pause</button>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <audio id="aud" style="width: 50%;" preload="metadata" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <!-- This source won't show the canvas visualization: -->
      <!--source src="media/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3" /-->
      <!-- But this one shows: -->
      <source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3">
      Your browser does not support the vedio tag.
    </audio>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 100%;">
    <canvas id="canvasEl" style="width: 88%; height: 100px;"></canvas>
  </div>
</body>
```

## Problem:

Safari shows canvas visualization with this audio source:

```html
<source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3">
```

But when I place the exact same audio file in a public location and serve it statically, like this this as the audio source:

```html
<source src="media/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3">
```

...the audio is played but the canvas visualization is not shown. Due to Web Audio API analyzer node output being all `128` and not changing. It means the analyzer node is *not* outputting anything.

## Note

I serve the web page statically by `python3 -m http.server` on my machine.

## Question

Only the Safari browser shows different behavior for these two, why?

```html
<!-- This source works fine: -->
<source src="https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3">
```

```html
<!-- This source doesn't show the canvas visualization but the audio sound is played: -->
<source src="media/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3">
```

## Occasional observation

In the case of `<source src="media/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3">` the *play/pause* button, occasionally starts the audio from the beginning. I mean, it doesn't pick the sound where it left off. It just restarts the sound.

But with the other source, the *play/pause* behaves as expected.

The above occasional observation is accompanied by such a network communication:

[image: HTTP header]

Comment: Try removing `crossorigin="anonymous"` on your `<audio>` tag. (Might also need a few "Empty Caches")

Comment: @Kaiido I removed `crossorigin="anonymous"` attribute and used `<source src="media/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3">`.  Like before, the sound is played but canvas visualization is not shown due to bad analyzer node output :( I also clicked *Empty Caches* multiple times.

Comment: ...weird, I can't repro on my system. Maybe looking at the network tab and searching for what's different in the response headers might shed some light.

Comment: @Kaiido Just to double-check, does `<source src="media/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3">` show the canvas visualization on your system?

Comment: Yes it does. But chances are great that our two servers are configured differently.

Comment: @Kaiido I simply serve by `python3 -m http.server` =)

Comment: @Kaiido I'm using Safari 13.1.2 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Works on Safari 15.1 on Monterey (even with python's http.server). But look at your response's headers, you don't see anything different?

Comment: @Kaiido Good idea :) I need to check the HTTP communication.

Comment: But are you really using the same file than the one hosted at https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_2MG.mp3? I feel you may face https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65009249/mp3-files-duration-infinity-in-desktop-ios-safari/65015045#65015045

Comment: @Kaiido I believe so :) I just downloaded it and placed it locally.

Comment: For me this one works fine, but the one in the linked Q.A exposes exactly the same behavior as you describe.

Comment: @Kaiido Right. I'm not sure, maybe the download process of the MP3 file changes it.